# Error Adding HU_CREATE_GOODSMVT_RFC with delphi TSAPFunction

Tags: delphi, sap-erp, saprfc

I'm using `TSAPFunction` to connect to SAP with Delphi 2009.

Everything works fine, I can use some BAPIU like (`RFC_READ_TABLE`, `BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE`, etc...).

I'm trying to use `HU_CREATE_GOODSMVT_RFC` but it doesn't work.

If I try to add functions from OCX I got this error

> Could not add functions

When I try to add it from this code :

```
FormClientSAP.SAPFunctionsWork.Add('HU_CREATE_GOODSMVT_RFC');
```

I tried with this code too :

```
myIFunction:=FormClientSAP.SAPFunctionsWork.Add('HU_CREATE_GOODSMVT_RFC') AS IFunction;
```

But my function isn't added `(FormClientSAP.SAPFunctionsWork.Count = 0)`.

I try with and without UNICODE components.

I've checked in SAP and this BAPI is RFC enabled. And from `SE37` I can use it and it works fine.

Can anyone can help me to understand what is wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the Add function return an error code or does the SAP OCX have some kind of GetLastError function/Variable you can interrogate?

Comment: Hi Andy, the add function doesn't return an error code but if i check the content of "myIFunction" it return nil (with an other BAPI it return a value.

Comment: Hi expert,
Nobody have an idea to understand what is wrong with this RFC ?
I really need to use it.
If you want more information, please ask.